# swagger.io: Not a valid parameter definition on header required property

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I'm documenting an API on swagger.io. When I try to define session_token as a required string property in the header, I get the error:

[image]

My definition matches the sample in the [documentation](http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject) so I'm not sure what
s causing the issue.

**Snippet**

```
/customerVerifyLogin:
    post:
      summary: Validate verification code sent to authenticate login. Returns session_token
      parameters:
        - name: Authorization
          in: header
          type: string
          required: true
          default: Basic YWRtaW46WDRCbzViWnZTamlXU0hoZDFMOGNpUHkyUERzekUwU3I=
        - name: session_type
          in: header
          type: string
          enum: 
            - android
            - ios
          required: true
        - name: VerificationCode
          in: body
          type: string
          required: true
          description:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              phone:
                type: string
                description: The mobile number to which the verification was sent.
              device_id:
                type: string
                description: ID that uniquely identifies the device
              code:
                in: body
                type: integer
                format: int32
                required: true
                description: Verification code to be validated.
      responses:
        200:
          description: Customer logged-in successfully.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Customer'
      tags:
        - Verification
        - Login
```

Answer (score 0):

a couple errors in your document:

- `VerificationCode` shows `type: string` and `schema:`.  For a body param (`in: body`), you can only use `schema`.  Just delete the `type: string`.
- Your definition for the property `code` has some unwanted fields:

  - Remove `in: body`.  That's probably a copy/paste error
  - Remove `required: true`.  That's not the correct way to say a property is required, move it to a sibling of the `properties` object like such:

> ```
> required:
>   - code
> properties:
>   code:
>    # the rest of your definition
> ```